# What technology is needed for this mmorts idea?

Tags: mmorts

I've got an idea for an real time strategy game like Starcraft or Age of Empires, but there is only one single massive persistent map or world with thousands of factions and each faction's units/buildings/resources are controlled by up to 64 players in team melee mode. Players can join any map and any faction they want to. Mined out resources respawn after a while if no player base or units are nearby. New players can join any time to an existing faction or create a new faction, which can be open or private. If a faction has no players online at the moment, then the computer takes over in easy mode. Units cannot be upgraded.

My question is what technologies would be included in a game like this? I have programmer background but I'm pretty new to game dev.

Comment: I think this question as it stands is far to broad to be appropriate (as well, "which technology to use" questions are off-topic and this is dangerously close to such a thing). I think you should consider refocusing your question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't envy the position you're in right now. You have a lot of things to research, and it's not entirely clear what it is you should research.

To know what technology to use, you would need a clearer design. But I imagine you don't want to start designing before you know what technology to use.

My advice? Start with a simple game and work up.

Beyond that? Most of the professional game engines will handle networking and 3d models. So it may just be an issue of finding the right game engine.

As for the persistent information management? You'll probably have to write that yourself. That's pretty specific.